# Session check in angular with a promise

Tags: angularjs, promise

I want to make sure, that my app checks on certain routs if it is still authenticated. To do that I added to my routes:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', 
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/profile',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/user/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
            resolve: [ 'SessionCheck' ]
    }).
    .......
```

I have a factory which handles the ['SessionCheck']

```
AppFactories.factory("SessionCheck", ['$http','$q','FlashService', 
  function($http,$q,FlashService) {

  var def = $q.defer();
  var SessionStatus = $http.get('/sessioncheck', {cache: false});
    if(SessionStatus.success){
      def.resolve();
    }else{
      FlashService.show(SessionStatus.data.flash);
      def.reject;
    }
    return def.promise;
```

}]);

I can see that the link is being called, but only once. Every time I click on a route with the resolve property the sessioncheck is not send to the server.... I already tried to put cache on false, but still. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put the service in run block http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',function(){}) just to give you a hint

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is how you are using the resolver. Try something like this:

in the factory:

```
AppFactories.factory("SessionCheck", ['$http','$q','FlashService', function($http,$q,FlashService) {

  return {

    resolve: function () {
      var def = $q.defer();
      var SessionStatus = $http.get('/sessioncheck', {cache: false});
      if(SessionStatus.success){
      def.resolve();
      }else{
      FlashService.show(SessionStatus.data.flash);
      def.reject;
      }
      return def.promise;
    }
  };
}]);
```

and in the router:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', 
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/profile',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/user/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
            resolve: [ 'SessionCheck', function(sessionCheck) { 
                   return sessionCheck.resolve();
            }]
    }).
    .......
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but I get the following error: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.3/$injector/unpr?p0=sessionCheckProvider%20%3C-%20sessionCheck